# OAuth認証について

Tags: android, java, oauth

アンドロイド開発初心者です。

OAuth認証についての質問があります。
現在、「画面上の「認証」ボタンを押すと、twitterの認証画面に移動する」というところまでの開発を行っています(練習アプリです)。
自分なりにコーディングしてみたのですが、「認証」を押すとエラーが出てアプリが落ちてしまいます。デバックもしてみたのですが原因がわかりません。

どなたか原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

以下諸情報
使っているライブラリ：
commons-codec-1.5.jar
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
ソースコード：
以下のページに記載してあります。
https://goo.gl/UtIITo
デバッグ時のLogcatのエラータブ：
[image]
<注>
twitter.java:57は Main Activity の
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
になります。
エラー詳細：
同アプリの「認証」ボタンを押すとほどなくして「問題が発生したため、同アプリを終了します」というコメントが出てきてアプリが落ちてしまいます
デバッグ詳細：
。 「デバッグ」に関しては、AndroidStudioに標準で付いているdebugツールを試してみて、LogCatでエラーが出た箇所を見直すという方法で行いました。‌​BreakPointなどは特に使用しておりません。

どうぞよろしくお願いします

Comment: エラーの内容も書かれていないデバッグ代行質問なので適切な回答が得られる可能性は薄いです。「エラー」の具体的な情報、スタックトレース、自分でやった「デバッグ」の詳細を質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 言葉が足りなくて申し訳ありませんでした。
「エラー」に関しては、同アプリの「認証」ボタンを押すとほどなくして「問題が発生したため、同アプリを終了します」というコメントが出てきてアプリが落ちてしまいます。LogCatの内容については本文に追記しました。
「デバッグ」に関しては、AndroidStudioに標準で付いているdebugツールを試してみて、LogCatでエラーが出た箇所を見直すという方法で行いました。BreakPointなどは特に使用しておりません。

Comment: コメントで返信するのではなく質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: keyが載ってますが大丈夫ですか？

Comment: 画像で貼り付けられてはコピーして検索したり回答に貼り付けたりするのも面倒ですから、次からはテキストで貼りつけていただけると助かります。もしコードやログを質問内に直接貼り付ける場合は、[範囲選択した上でエディタ上部 `{}` をクリックして整形すると](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/8000)見やすくなります。

Answer (score 4):

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }

指定されたIntentに対応するActivityが見つからない、というエラーですが、datの値が空になっているように見えます。対応するソースコードを読むと・・・

```
public void onClickBtnLogin(View v){
    String authUrl="";
    try{
        authUrl = oauthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(oauthConsumer,AppConstants.CALLBACK_URL);
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Twitter OAuth Error", e);
    } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Twitter OAuth Error", e);
    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Twitter OAuth Error", e);
    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Twitter OAuth Error", e);
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
}
```

これ、`oauthProvider.retrieveRequestToken()` に失敗しても `startActivity(new Intent(...))` が実行されますよね。この場合 `authUrl` は空文字列ですから、冒頭のエラーになることが考えられます。

authUrlが取得できなかった場合はstartActivityしないようにする必要があるのではないでしょうか。

いずれにせよ authUrlが正しいURLになっているかどうか確認してみてください。